# Issue in deleting data from core data through table view iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method I have implemented gesture recognizer for long press,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView == favouritesTable) {
    cellValue = [licensePlateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else { // handle search results table view
    cellValue = [filteredListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"vlCell";

VehicleListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Cell Created");

    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VehicleListCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[VehicleListCell class]]) {
            cell = (VehicleListCell *)currentObject;
        }
    }

}

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecongnizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellPressed:)];

toDeleteObject = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
pressRecongnizer.view.tag = indexPath.row;

pressRecongnizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecongnizer];
[pressRecongnizer release];

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

Favouritesdata *favdata = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[[cell ignition] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ignition.png"]];
[[cell direction] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"south.png"]];

cell.licPlate.text = [favdata licenseplate];

NSLog(@"cellvalue for cellforRow: %@", cell.licPlate.text);

return cell;}
```

And in `tableCellPressed`

```
- (void)tableCellPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    return;
}

VehicleListCell* cell = (VehicleListCell *)[recognizer view];

cellValueForLongPress = cell.licPlate.text;

NSLog(@"cell value: %@", cellValueForLongPress);

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil] ;

alert.tag = recognizer.view.tag;

[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Remove from Favourites"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Show on Map"];

[alert show];}
```

And in `alertView:`

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSString *title = [alert buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if([title isEqualToString:@"Remove from Favourites"])
{
    NSLog(@"cellValueForLongPress: %@", cellValueForLongPress);

    [results removeObjectAtIndex:alert.tag];

    [context deleteObject:toDeleteObject];

    NSLog(@"alert.tag:::: %d", alert.tag);   

}
else if([title isEqualToString:@"Show on Map"])
{
    NSLog(@"Go to MapView");

    Maps *detailViewFromLabel = [Maps alloc];

    [self.view addSubview:detailViewFromLabel.view];

}

NSError *error;

if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error Occured");
}

[favouritesTable reloadData];}
```

Through this code entry from the core data gets deleted but the issue is that it only deletes the entry at index:0 and not the entry which is selected from the table.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it backwards anyway, but here is your problem:

```
pressRecongnizer.view.tag = indexPath.row; // view is nil at this point 
pressRecongnizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f; 
[cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecongnizer]; // now we have a view!
[pressRecongnizer release];
```

You set the tag on the view of pressRecogniser before you set the view itself. So you are setting a tag to nothing, ending up with zero as the tag and this is the row you keep deleting.

Add a gesture recogniser to your cell when it is first created (if cell==nil) then in your action method get hold of the index path of the cell (UITableView has a method for this, `indexPathForCell:`), and use that to determine which element you have selected and which element should be deleted.

Comment: I have implemented the gesture recognizer in cell creation method, now how can I get hold of the index path of the cell. can you help me with that?

Comment: indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:recognizer.view];

Comment: In your action method. Probably have it as an ivar, then you can refer to it from the alert view delegate method later on, instead of using all these tags.

Answer (score 0):

How about having your uitableviewcell subclass implement the gesture recognizer and this can also hold a reference to your data object. This would be a lot neater.

Assuming your view controller is holding your data model (bad idea really), you could then communicate back using either a delegate or notification pattern.

Here is something off the top of my head

```
@interface VehicleListCell 
@property (nonatomic, retain) VehicleClass *vehicle;
@end

@implementation VehicleListCell

@synthesize vehicle;

- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle) style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    if (self) {
       //add your gesture recogniser to self using the same code you have
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tableCellPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    return;
}
[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName: @"VehicleDeleted" withObject: self userInfo: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: vehicle andKey: @"vehicle"]]
}
@end
```